# Eclipse keeps crashing when I access specific classes

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a problem with my Eclipse: it keeps crashing with no error message when I access some classes. I just open one class file, scroll down a bit or type maximum a line, and Eclipse crashes for no reason. Does anyone have a solution?

This is my config file:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

Logs:

```
!SESSION 2016-08-13 15:56:27.837 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.2.M20150204-1700
java.version=1.8.0_92
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

This is a continuation of log file C:\Users\Andrew\workspace\.metadata\.bak_0.log
Created Time: 2016-08-13 15:56:29.116
!SESSION 2016-08-13 15:56:27.837 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.2.M20150204-1700
java.version=1.8.0_92
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2016-08-13 15:56:29.119
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2016-08-13 15:56:36.126
!MESSAGE Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level
Git settings which might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git installation directory.
The most important of these settings is core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true in
this system level configuration. The Git installation location can be configured on the
Team > Git > Configuration preference page's 'System Settings' tab.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2016-08-13 15:56:36.239
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\Andrew'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
!SESSION 2016-08-13 15:57:24.177 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.2.M20150204-1700
java.version=1.8.0_92
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2016-08-13 15:57:25.530
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2016-08-13 15:57:32.998
!MESSAGE Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level
Git settings which might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git installation directory.
The most important of these settings is core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true in
this system level configuration. The Git installation location can be configured on the
Team > Git > Configuration preference page's 'System Settings' tab.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
```

Comment: do you have a log file usually can be found at `workspace/.metadata/.log`

Comment: edited...i hope it's enough

Comment: I heard about such an issue with a specific Java-version. I might be 1.8 update 92 that you use. Does it work with another version?

Comment: It seems from warning that you need to set atleast a local variable called `HOME` that points to `C:\Users\Andrew` and restart eclipse.

Comment: That's just a warning from eGit. It shouldn't cause a crash. @AndreiXwe have you tried this exact scenario with the current Eclipse release and latest version of Java 8?

Comment: yeah, I guess the update 92 was the problem. I installed 101 instead and eclipse hasn't crashed so far

Comment: unfortunately,  it happens again, but this time it takes a bit more time until it crashes

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

I solved it by executing Eclipse updates under Help -> Check for Updates.
Running on java 1.8.0_92 as JRE.

My eclipse.ini:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.401.v20161122-1740
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx4096m
```

If this does not solve the problem for you, check which editor you are using for opening file: right click on file -> "Open With" and you will see the standard editor. The issue should be with editor. Of course you could try to open with another editor(s) and if Eclipse is stil crashing, its not an editor issue...